# How to import large csv data with Chinese characters in RStudio

Tags: r

I want to import `data.csv` with Chinese characters by RStudio  , but it fails (see below ). So I want to open the file to figure what’s wrong with the data by excel, but the file is too large to open (470M). What should I do?

```
dat <- read.csv("data.csv",header=T,encoding = "UTF-8",stringsAsFactors = F)
```

> Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 多字节字符串1有错

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `make.names`, you can avoid calling that by adding `check.names=FALSE` as a parameter to `read.csv`. You may end up with syntactically invalid names though.

Comment: There are apparently duplicate column names - but without Chinese language skills probably difficult to eliminate. Try @James solution and try to change column names for your needs.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: It failed as below @James
data2 <-read.csv("data.csv", header=T, encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = F, check.names = FALSE) 
Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, : '<c7><ef>'多字节字符串有错

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution: Split the large file into several parts by Free Huge CSV Splitter. Open the small file by excel, and save as CSV UTF-8 format. Then imported to RStudio sucessfully.